Motion Planning With Moveit 2 & ROS2 Humble - Executing a Specific Action
I'm very new to Ros and Moveit, but I've slowly gotten a stronger understanding on things. I've just completed the Moveit2 Humble 'Pick and Place with Moveit Task Constructor' tutorial "https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/moveit_task_constructor/moveit_task_constructor_tutorial.html" and I've successfully created and executed actions like 'pick object' and 'place object' in RViz. I would now like to:

Save these actions as predefined tasks.
Trigger these tasks programmatically in my code or via terminal commands using specific keywords (e.g., 'pickup').

For context, I'm using ROS 2 Humble with MoveIt 2 on Linux through Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Any guidance or support on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!.
